# WordPress wp-block-file__button Colour Change?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress site and running into a problem. I have a list on a page including download buttons, only I can't seem to work out how to change the colour of the button or the font? The code is as follows:

```
class="wp-block-file__button" download>Download</a></div>
```

How would I go about formatting the button here?

Thanks

Comment: well you might want to start by editing the related css.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where is your button (admin panel or theme):

**For admin panel** (Add to function.php)

```
<?php add_action( 'admin_head', 'theme_admin_css' );
function theme_admin_css() {
echo '
<style>
.wp-block-file__button {
  background-color: red!important;
  color: white!important;
}
</style>'; ?>
```

**OR if in actual theme** (Add to your style.css)

```
.wp-block-file__button {
  background-color: red!important;
  color: white!important;
}
```